# Installing node.js package Taunus on WIndows 10

Tags: c++, .net, node.js, windows, npm

I am trying to install Taunus locally on my Windows 10, following [how-to-guide](http://taunus.io/getting-started#setting-up-the-server-side).

1. I have installed Node.js.
2. I have installed Python 2.7.
3. I get some error with strange symbols, something about .NET and C++.
4. I have installed latest windows updates and also tried to set up C++ [distributing package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555)

But at the end I stiil get the error:

```
vokec@DESKTOP-LQHIC1P MINGW64 /e/dev/getting-started
$ npm install --save taunus taunus-express express
npm WARN package.json getting-started@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json getting-started@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json getting-started@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.8
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'

> contextify@0.1.14 install E:\dev\getting-started\node_modules\taunus\node_modules\hget\node_modules\html-md\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\dev\getting-started\node_modules\taunus\node_modules\hget\node_modules\html-md\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
▒▒▒▒஥▒▒▒ ▒஥▒⮢ ▒ ▒⮬ ▒襭▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒. ▒⮡▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ࠫ▒▒▒쭮▒ ▒▒▒▒஥▒▒▒, ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ࠬ▒▒▒ "/m".
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: ▒▒▒▒㧪▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe" ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒. ▒▒▒ᮡ▒ ▒襭▒▒ ▒஡▒▒▒▒: 1) ▒▒⠭▒▒▒▒ .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) ▒▒⠭▒▒▒▒ Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ▒▒▒ 3) 㪠▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒ ▒▒⥬▒▒▒ ▒▒▒, ▒᫨ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒⠭▒▒▒▒▒ ▒ ▒▒㣮▒ ▒▒▒▒.  [E:\dev\getting-started\node_modules\taunus\node_modules\hget\node_modules\html-md\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\dev\getting-started\node_modules\taunus\node_modules\hget\node_modules\html-md\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "taunus" "taunus-express" "express"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.14 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\dev\getting-started\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by installing Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition with checked C++ language.